# Why can't I edit to improve an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, rejected-edits

I accepted an answer to my question and then realised two things:

1. The answer, although useful, gave a slightly different outcome to the one I asked for.
2. There was a bug in the answer.

So [I suggested two changes to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15938420), one adding an alternate version which gave the required outcome, the other fixing the bug (deleting a few characters of code). Both changes were rejected by peer review with the reason: *This edit deviates from the original intent of the post*.

Why were the changes rejected as they improved the relevance of the answer to the question posed?

Answer (score 3):

It was correct to reject this because, as the rejection message says, the edit deviates from the original intent of the post; the original poster didn't create that design, so accepting that edit would basically be putting words in the poster's mouth.

In cases like this, the correct thing would be to either comment on the post asking for the modification or add your own answer with the alternative design.

Comment: OK, thanks. I can see how that applied to the first edit, but the second edit merely corrected a bug in the posters answer. It did not deviate from his intention.

Comment: @doctorer Then submit that as a separate, specific edit, with a clear edit summary (there's no way to accept just *part* of an edit).